# Flex dictionary literal

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Working in Flex I need to populate Dictionaries with a fairly involved structure.  Based on [this documentation page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html) I tried creating a dictionary literal via the following syntax:

```
    var defaultMarkingA =
        {
            type: 'page',
            displayText: 'XYZ',
            innerMarkings: [
                {id: 'ABC', type: 'page', displayText: 'ABC'}
            ]
        };
```

What I expect this code to create is a nested Dictionary structure with three mappings:

1. "type" -> "page"
2. "displayText" -> "XYZ"
3. "innerMarkings" => single-element array with another Dictionary inside containing:

   1. "id" -> "ABC"
   2. "type" -> "page"
   3. "displayText" -> "ABC"

What the code actually creates is an "Object" according to getQualifiedClassName.  What am I doing wrong here?  Is actionscript unable to deal with a nested Dictionary literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong that's just not the way to make the structure you want. Using `something = {}` is shorthand for `something = new Object()`. There is no such shorthand to create a `Dictionary`.

From [the docs you linked](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html):

> An associative array is an instance of the Object class, which means
>   that each key corresponds to a property name.

and

> ActionScript 3.0 introduces an advanced type of associative array
>   called a dictionary. Dictionaries, which are instances of the
>   Dictionary class in the flash.utils package, use keys that can be of
>   any data type but are usually instances of the Object class. In other
>   words, dictionary keys are not limited to values of type String.

To get your expected result you'd have to do the following:

```
var defaultMarkingA:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
defaultMarkingA["type"] = "page";
defaultMarkingA["displayText"] = "XYZ";
defaultMarkingA["innerMarkings"] = new Array();

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dict["id"] = "ABC";
dict["type"] = "page";
dict["displayText"] = "ABC";

defaultMarkingA["innerMarkings"].push(dict);
```

There is nothing wrong with using an `Object` as an associative array. The only problem I could see is that performance may differ between using `Object` and `Dictionary` but you'd need to do some profiling to see if a) there is any difference and b) if that difference matters.

Comment: Dictionaries and objects mainly differ in the type of keys they support. The keys in objects are always stringed, whereas dictionaries can support keys of any type.

Comment: I +1ed your answer, but one thing is not quite right: Dictionary is a subclass of Object, which essentially means that any value associated with a String key will be handled in exactly the same way it is handled by Object. Thus, there is no performance difference.  Dictionaries generally don't bring an advantage, unless they are used with Object keys, because of the way data is referenced in ActionScript: Objects are passed around as pointers, whereas primitive values (int, uint, Number, String) are passed by value - which also makes the concept of "weakKeys" irrelevant.

Comment: The lack of the syntax I want is unfortunate.  Also, Object being an associative array is... quite bizarre.  Thanks for the info.